# Fuzzy matching in Perl

Tags: perl, fuzzy-comparison

I want to do some fuzzy matching with different strings, like,
`air twist` should match with `air-twist` or `air twists` or `air-twists`.

In perl, do we have some module to do that? or can we do that manually, like using Regex?

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40010321/4653379) for a scoop on modules and approaches, with links

Comment: I like the `String::Similarity` one. :) It's easy to use.

Comment: Yeah, it's nice to have options to choose from :).  They all differ a little in best uses.  Another example in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52712576/4653379) ...  I hope these are useful enough so there is no need to write them up here?

Comment: Good tutorial already. `String::Approx` is perfect for another scenario I was thinking about: Add HTML tags around a fuzzy match of a target string. :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like following code does the job

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $regex = qr/air.twists{0,1}/;

while( <DATA> ) {
    print if /$regex/;
}

__DATA__
air-twist
air balloon
air twists
fried potato
air-twist
Cesar salad
air-propeller
air show
broken car
new bicycle
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to match any non-alphanumeric character between two specific words, you could use a regex like this:

```
/air[^a-z0-9]twists/i
```

The `[^a-z0-9]` matches any character that is *not* a letter or digit; so it will match things like a space or punctuation character. The trailing `i` suffix tells the regex to ignore letter case.

This particular regex will match strings like the following:

```
air twists
AIR TWISTS
Air-Twists
AIR_TWISTS
air/twists
air.twists
air:twists
```

... and so on.

If you want to match more than one non-alphanumeric character separating the words, add a `+` to the regex:

```
/air[^a-z0-9]+twists/i
```

This matches more strings, like these:

```
air  twists
air---twists
air, twists
air && twists
air<=>twists
```